# UNIX: log into DB in SQLPLUS on background, use that background conection for query execution

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

Is it possible in Unix to login Oracle DB via sqlplus (everything in bash), stay connected (just login into DB, don't execute any query) in background and use that process (connection) in other processes to execute SQL queries?

So use that connection as "pipe" to Oracle?

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended question... I'd suggest researching bash subshells and IPC and then coming up with a more specific question to ask. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132102/communication-between-multiple-processes

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1.**
You can run script `pipe.sh` in the background. And in another session, send sql files or sql. With reconnect after run sql.

```
more pipe.sh

#!/bin/bash

rm /tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql
mknod /tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql p

while :
do

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus   "system/manager" <<EOF
@/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql
EOF

sleep 1
done
```

run this script in backgroud

```
   nohup ./pipe.sh  >pipe_log.log 2>&1  &
```

In other bash session you can send sql file or sql  to this backgroud process.

```
oracle@esmd:/tmp> cat test2.sql >>/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/tmp> cat test2.sql >>/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql

oracle@esmd:/tmp> echo "select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;" >>/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/tmp> echo "select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;" >>/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql


oracle@esmd:/tmp> more test2.sql
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;



oracle@esmd:~> more pipe_log.log

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Aug 8 14:50:35 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
08-08-2019 14:50:46

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Aug 8 14:50:47 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
08-08-2019 14:50:48

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Aug 8 14:50:49 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
08-08-2019 14:50:49

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

Update.
**Example 2.**
You can run script `pipev2.sh` in the background on the Oracle database server. And in another session, send sql files or sql. Without reconnect after run sql.

```
 nohup ./pipev2.sh >output.log 2>&1 &

#!/bin/bash

rm /home/trs/db2Toora/sql/sqlplus_pipe.sql
mknod /home/trs/db2Toora/sql/sqlplus_pipe.sql p


$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus   "system/manager" <<EOF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
    BEGIN
      RUN_SQL;
    END;
/
EOF


CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEMP_DIR_CHANGE AS '/home/trs/db2Toora/sql'
/
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY TEMP_DIR_CHANGE TO SYSTEM
/
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY TEMP_DIR_CHANGE TO SYSTEM
/


    CREATE OR REPALCE PROCEDURE RUN_SQL

is
    sql_text VARCHAR2(2000);
    file_sql_name VARCHAR2(100):='sqlplus_pipe.sql';
    sql_delimiter VARCHAR2(1):=';';
    stop_script VARCHAR2(10):='%QUIT%';
    sql_output VARCHAR2(2000);
    InFile           utl_file.file_type;
    vNewLine         VARCHAR2(4000);
    k  pls_integer :=0;
    BEGIN
    dbms_output.enable;
    while k <>1
    loop
    InFile := utl_file.fopen('TEMP_DIR_CHANGE', file_sql_name,'r');

    LOOP
      BEGIN

      utl_file.get_line(InFile, vNewLine);

      if vNewLine like '%'||sql_delimiter||'%' then
         sql_text:=sql_text||vNewLine;
      dbms_output.put_line(sql_text);
       begin

        execute immediate replace(sql_text,sql_delimiter,'' ) into sql_output;

        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('!---!--Error--!---!');
        dbms_output.put_line(substr(sqlerrm, 1, 500));
       end;
      dbms_output.put_line(sql_output);
      dbms_output.put_line('---------------------------------------------------------------');
      sql_text:='';
      elsif vNewLine like  stop_script then
      dbms_output.put_line('---!--QUIT--!---');
      EXIT;
      else
      sql_text:=sql_text||vNewLine;
      end if;

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        EXIT;
      END;


    END LOOP;
      if vNewLine like stop_script then
       exit;
      end if;

end loop;

    utl_file.fclose(InFile);

    END;
```

Test

```
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> echo 'QUIT'  >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql>


oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> more test2.sql
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from dual
;
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
from dual
;


nohup: ignoring input

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Aug 13 10:11:23 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4  select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:34
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:35
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:35
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:36
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:36
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:37
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 12:19
---------------------------------------------------------------
---!--QUIT--!---

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```